# Extracting the time of the paved route in the maps

Tags: android, google-maps, maps, yandex-maps

i`m using the maps in my app. I am entering location, and maps opens. For example, i've get direction there. Maps calculate the necessary time to get to the entered point. Can i programmatically get this time for using in my app?

Here is fragment of code with maps.

```
        Button destination_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        destination_button.getBackground().setAlpha(64);

        final EditText destination_tw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        destination_button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String string_for_entering_destination;

                string_for_entering_destination = "q=" + destination_tw.getText().toString() + "&z=8";
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//              String geoUriString = "geo:0,10?z=2";
                String geoUriString = "geo:0,0?" + string_for_entering_destination;
                Uri geoUri = Uri.parse(geoUriString);
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, geoUri);
                startActivity(mapIntent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need to use the Google Maps Api (Web) i think that the Android Maps Api does not return the route duration.

Use this reference to implement: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions

You are going to make an Http request with the requested parameters such as startPoint and EndPoint and the API will send you back a JSON response with the a bunch of info like duration time.